# Разделение проекта?

Tags: php, apache, angularjs, laravel

Как реализовать отдельные части angular и laravel.

Подразумевается что angular будет как front-end, laravel - backend,
как именно реализовать разделение по папкам?
Нужно реализовать на сервере laravel и уже внутри него создавать папку с angular проектом?

Спасибо за ответы заранее.

Answer (score 1):

По сути, связывать их будет только спецификация API, общего кода между ними не будет, поэтому нет смысла держать их в одном проекте. Пусть это будут два отдельных проекта.

Так будет проще организация, если вы, например, решите сделать для тестирования оболочки бэкенд с заглушками. Или решите сделать другую оболочку (админку?). Вам не придётся думать о привязке к путям между компонентами, если её просто не будет.

В конфигурации сервера nginx, если использовать его как прозрачный прокси, можно "попытаться отдать статический файл", а если не выйдет, передать запрос дальше, например в API. Директива называется `try_files`.